# how to set the Bitrate converting mp4 and flv video to mp3 with VLC

Tags: audio-recording, video-processing, vlc, libvlc

I run the following command in order to convert `flv video` to `mp3` by using `VLC` in command line mode:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -I dummy \
"myFile.flv" \
--sout='#transcode{acodec=mp3,vcodec=dummy}:standard{access=file,mux=raw,dst="myFile.flv.mp3"}' \
vlc://quit
```

The Bitrate of the mp3 file is usually too high and the files takes too space on the disk.
My question is:   how can I set the Bitrate by using VLC by command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only for this, but for any VLC command the simplest way is to do the same with the GUI, (in your case setup transcode, select input file, select transcoding options, select output to a file) it will give you the command line that it itself uses at the bottom of the GUI on the final screen and then copy and use that on your command line.